Is "keep me true" used in professional context?
Some of my US colleagues used the phrase "John, keep me true" in a business meeting context, meaning something like "John, correct me if I am wrong".
But when I google it, I get only religious context. Is it normally used in professional conversation?

They used it? More than once? Where in the US? I never heard it but yes it could be an odd way of saying, correct me if I'm wrong.

@Lambie As swmcdonnell says, "keep me honest" is more common; I've encountered that often. This could be understood as a somewhat fumbled spoken variant.

'True' has multiple uses. Most commonly, it means correct, or right - the opposite of false, or incorrect.
A secondary use of the word means straight, or accurate. For example, if a wall or similar construction is true then it has been built straight, not skewed, and fits correctly with other parts of the construction. 'True' is also used to describe a trajectory - a path or direction of travel being followed. If a trajectory, or path is 'true' that means it is straight and not deviating to the left or right. It is this use that you are finding in a religious context - many people ask their deity to keep them 'true', meaning to keep them on the figurative path of following their religion.
Your quotation sounds like it matches this secondary meaning, but I agree that it is surprising to hear the phrase used in the stated context. I'm even wondering if you have heard it correctly. Could you have possibly misheard? Note that some phrases like this may have fallen from use in some dialects of English such as American or British English, but may be more in use among other dialects, so if you think the phrase makes sense in context then it may well be right.

"Keep me true" is probably less common than "John, keep me honest."
Both are very informal ways of saying, "John, tell me if I say something that's not correct."
They are used in a business context, but are very informal. After the speaker finishes, John is probably obligated to make a comment such as,"Everything you've said is correct, as far as I know."

@daniel.sedlacek There's almost a bit of exaggerative humor involved, as an accidental mistake through misinformation is not a "lie." (Also, I wouldn't say the speaker definitely expects John to confirm out loud; just that he expects him to chime in if the speaker is incorrect.)
